# How to upload a file when using JQuery serialize()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file, serialization

My code is structured as follows:

**HTML**

```
<form autocomplete='off' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' onSubmit='updateConfig(this);return false;'>

<tr><td>DKIM</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='dkim' id='dkim'   class='toggle' ".$dkim->dkim." />&nbsp;<label for='data'></label></td></tr>
<tr><td>DKIM-Key</td><td><input type='file' name='dkim_key' id='dkim_key'  ".$dkim->dkim_key." />&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td>DKIM-Selector</td><td><input class='form-control' name='dkim_selector' id='dkim_selector' value='".$dkim->dkim_selector."' /></label></td></tr>
<tr><td>DKIM-Passphrase</td><td><input class='form-control' type='password' name='dkim_passphrase' id='dkim_passphrase' value='".$dkim->dkim_passphrase."' /></label></td></tr>";
```

**JS**

```
var updateConfig = function (form) {
    $.post('/path/conf_update.php', $(form).serialize(), function (data) {
        setAlert('Konfiguration aktualisiert', 'Die Konfiguration wurde erfolgreich aktualisiert.',
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="">OK</button>');
    });
};
```

**PHP (conf_update.php)**

```
$dkim = new stdClass();
  
$dkim->dkim = $_POST['dkim'];
  
$dkim->dkim_key = $_FILES['dkim_key']['tmp_name'];
$dkim->dkim_selector = $_POST['dkim_selector'];
$dkim->dkim_passphrase = $_POST['dkim_passphrase'];
error_log("DKIM:--- ".print_r($_FILES, true));
```

dkim, dkim_selector and dkim_passphrase work. But $_FILES is empty. I'm sure it's the JS, but I don't know how to change it to get the filename.